# In Pandas dataframe, how to add metadata to a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating my own module for calculation of price indicators, and I would like to add metadata to a column of a dataframe, so each column will have unique metadata.

It is important for me since I have multiple functions and I can recalculate output of one function using another function, also I use some functions to do calculations inside the function I am calling.

For example:

```
def average_day_range(price_df: PandasDataFrame, n: int=14, calculation_tool: int=0):
    '''
    0 - SMA, 1 - EMA, 2 - WMA, 3 - EWMA, 4 - VWMA,  5 - ALMA, 6 - LSMA, 7 - HULL MA
    :param price_df:
    :param n:
    :param calculation_tool:
    :return:
    '''
    if calculation_tool not in range(0, 8, 1):
        calculation_tool = 0
    else:
        pass
    function_dict = {
        0: {
            "func": sma,
            "name": "SMA"
        },
        1: {
            "func": ema,
            "name": "EMA"
        },
        2: {
            "func": wma,
            "name": "WMA"
        },
        3: {
            "func": ewma,
            "name": "EWMA"
        },
        4: {
            "func": volume_weighted_moving_average,
            "name": "VWMA"
        },
        5: {
            "func": arnaud_legoux_ma,
            "name": "ALMA"
        },
        6: {
            "func": least_squares_moving_average,
            "name": "LSMA"
        },
        7: {
            "func": hull_ma,
            "name": "HULL_MA"
        },
    }

    function, name = function_dict[calculation_tool]["func"], function_dict[calculation_tool]["name"]
    high_var = function(price_df=price_df, input_mode=3, n=n, from_price=True)
    low_var = function(price_df=price_df, input_mode=4, n=n, from_price=True)
    adr = high_var[f'{name}_{n}'] - low_var[f'{name}_{n}']
    adr.rename(columns={0: f'Average Day Range {name}{n}'}, inplace=True)
    return adr
```

As you see I can use different functions to do calculations inside one function, and then if I would like to I can recalculate the output using different functions.

So I want to avoid naming columns like `func1 with func2 from func3` etc, because it is very confusing not to mention the horrendously long column names. Also, I don't want to store multiple dataframes separately but to concatenate the main dataframe with raw data and the dataframe with calculated output.

So let's say I have a dataframe with such columns `datetime, open, close, high, low, volume, indicator1, indicator2`.

How do I add metadata to each column in dataframe separately so I will be able to easily identify the column I am looking at? I would like to metadata to contain informations such as the source of the calculation (if it was `open, high close` or `low` or something else) and other.
(Identifying columns when there are only a couple of them is easy, but if I have ~50 columns, with names that are very similar to each other, then anybody who is looking at it will be just confused).

If adding the metadata to each column is not possible, is there maybe a way to connect a `.json` file to each column? If I have a wrong thinking process, is there another way to do what I want to do?